# Trouble with the while loop

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to write a simple code that when given , 2 numbers, one integer and the other the divisor, how to return the number of times the given integer can be divided by the divisor until the quotient is less than 1. I got it to divide the two numbers but I cant figure out how to get it to tell me the amount of numbers that were divided.

Example:

```
123 / 2
```

Should return a value of

```
7
```

My code:

```
def another_one(integer, divisor):
    while integer > 0:
        integer //= divisor
        print(integer)
    return integer
```

Thanks

Comment: Just keep track of the number of times the loop runs

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to keep track of the number of times the loop iterates:

```
def another_one(integer, divisor):
    count = 0
    while integer > 0:
        integer //= divisor
        print(integer)
        count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly. Perhaps you need something like this

```
def another_one(integer, divisor):
    counter = 0
    while integer > 0:
        counter += 1
        integer //= divisor
        print(integer)
    return counter

print(another_one(123, 2))
```

Comment: It would probably be better for you to leave a comment to the question and explore exactly what the user wants than to take a guess at an answer.